# Is there a way to toggle the relative number setting in Visual mode and only for the current window?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to toggle relative line numbers by pressing the F2 key. I have the following in my `.vimrc` file.

```
  " toggle relative line numbers
  function! RelativeNumberToggle()
      if (&number == 0)
          set number
      elseif (&relativenumber == 1)
          setlocal norelativenumber
      else
          setlocal relativenumber
      endif
  endfunction
  noremap <silent> <F2> :call RelativeNumberToggle()<CR>
```

This works in Normal mode, but it has two problems:

1. When I enter Visual mode and press F2 to toggle relative line numbers, the selection is lost and I'm back in Normal mode.
2. In Normal mode, despite using `setlocal` to toggle the relative number setting only for the current window, the relative number setting is toggled for all windows.

Is there a way to toggle the relative number setting in Visual mode and only for the current window?

I should mention that I also tried activating/deactivating relative line numbers using the `ModeChanged` Event so that relative line numbers are enabled when Visual mode is entered and disabled when the editor leaves Visual mode.
Activating relative line numbers when entering Visual mode is easy, `ModeChanged *:[vV\x16]` does the job. The problem is disabling relative line numbers when the editor exits Visual mode because it is loaded with special cases: For example, after yanking or deleting text, the editor switches to Normal mode, but the `ModeChanged [vV\x16]:*` and `ModeChanged *:n` Events are not fired—so relative line numbers are not disabled. I can fix this using the `TextYankPost` Event. However, after formatting a visual selection with `=` or `>` , the editor also drops to Normal mode and relative line numbers are not disabled. I do not know how to fix this last special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Vim is recent enough (8.2.1978 and up), you can use `<Cmd>` to execute Ex commands in your mappings without really leaving the current mode:

```
noremap <silent> <F2> <Cmd>call RelativeNumberToggle()<CR>
```

Your function needs attention, too. As-is, it does two things:

1. enable `&number` when it is disabled,
2. toggle `&relativenumber`.

The first thing could be simplified to:

```
set number
```

because enabling an option when it is already enabled essentially does nothing.

The second thing could also be simplified since there already is a a toggling mechanism for boolean options that doesn't require checking the current value:

```
setlocal relativenumber!
```

or:

```
setlocal invrelativenumber
```

Which means that you don't really need that function anymore since you can have the exact same functionality with a lot less boilerplate:

```
noremap <silent> <F2> <Cmd>set number <bar> setlocal relativenumber!<CR>
```

[image: toggle]

Reference:

- `:help :map-cmd`
- `:help :set-!`
- `:help map-bar`

Comment: Could you elaborate why @Bidit version changes all windows?

Comment: @kosciej16 I can't elaborate on that problem because I can't reproduce it.